# Where to call sqlalchemy configure_mappers with multiple Python modules

Tags: sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-continuum

I have a multiple class sqlalchemy implemented model. It spans multiple Python modules and includes relationships that reach across those modules as well. I want to add versioning to my model and I've decided to use sqlalchemy-continuum.

In [sqlalchemy-continuum's documentation](https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) it says "after you have defined all your models, call configure_mappers:". But they use a single Python module as an example.

Question: When using a multiple Python modules to implement a sqlalchemy model, where should sqlalchemy's utility function configure_mappers be called so that it its only called after all models have been defined?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?